# Is there anything wrong with a Runnable object containing a Thread member?

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider the following object:

```
public class Mindblower implements Runnable {

    private Thread ownThread;        

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do all the things
    }

    public Mindblower() {
        ownThread = new Thread(this);
        ownThread.start();
    }
}
```

Does this work? Will the fact that the Thread is a member of the Runnable being passed to the Thread matter? It seems to me like it should work, but thinking about it makes my head hurt as if I was watching a Christopher Nolan movie.

For bonus points, does it matter if `.start()` is called within the Runnable's constructor?

Comment: Instead of thinking so hard, why don't you run it and see what happens?

Comment: Threadception!
No but it should work... i think O.o.

Comment: Concerning `start()` from the constructor: that's a bug! It can cause multithreading problems. Lots of concurrency guarantees (such as the visibility of `final` fields) go out the window when `this` escapes to another thread from the constructor. In your case, `this` is passed to a `Thread` object in the constructor, and that `Thread` object is then started, causing it to access `this.run` from that other thread -- this constitutes a leak of `this` to another thread from within `this`'s constructor.

Comment: This is more or less what I'm looking for, so if you submit it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @RohitJain +1 if this wasn't about multi-threading. Unfortunately, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works, but you might want to consider a few other ways to accomplish this and make your code easier to understand.  You could create a second `Runnable` class to call from your main class, for instance:

```
public class Mindblower {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread ownThread = new Thread(new MindblowingRunnable());
    ownThread.start();

    // Other stuff that you want done concurrently on the main thread
  }

  private class MindblowingRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // Stuff to be carried out in your thread
    }
  }
}
```

This can be made a little simpler if the `Runnable` will only be used in that context, so long as the `Runnable` class need not be public:

```
public class Mindblower {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread ownThread = new MindblowingThread();
    ownThread.start();

    // Other stuff that you want done concurrently on the main thread
  }

  private class MindblowingThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // Stuff to be carried out in your thread
    }
  }
}
```

While you can keep a local reference to a thread, this is only useful if you need to interrupt it from your main thread.  From within the `Runnable`, just call `Thread.currentThread()`.

For your bonus question, there's no need to call `start()` from the constructor, or even from `main()`.  Both of these are options if you want your thread to run as soon as your program starts, but in some cases you may prefer to wait for user input first and call `start()` from some other method.

All of this assumes that you are only creating a single thread, or that if there are multiple threads, that synchronization between them is not an issue for your program.  If synchronization matters, consider a [Thread Pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) instead.

Comment: This is more or less how I would approach it. The question in OP was meant to be a pair of what-ifs and this answer addresses both of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of `Runnable` is to seperate the *what needs to be done* from the actual thread/execution component. By mixing both you don't get any benefit from using `Runnable` (except not using your *extends slot*)

In your case extending `Thread` and overriding `run()` would get you the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It works.

But that a reeeeeaaally bad practice

Comment: I agree, it seems like it is not a great idea and probably is not something that I would do. My concern is with whether or not that would mechanically cause problems (some crazy recursive stack overflow or something like that.)

Comment: there's no recursive stuff

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no point in doing this because the thread you are running in is always accessable from `Thread.currentThread()`.

Also - if you want to auto-start you should use something like this but this is still not advisable. A user of your class may want to do other things before starting your thread.

```
public class Mindblower implements Runnable {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    // You can access your thread at any time - you can even interrupt yourself.
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  }

  public Mindblower() {
    // Do not start here.
  }

  {
    // A more acceptable way of having a self-starting thread but still not a good idea.
    new Thread(this).start();
  }
}
```